# How to compare last two letters of a string in alphabetical order in Java?

Tags: java, string

I am having a problem comparing last two alphabetic letters of a single string in alphabetical order. I know how to compare two strings alphabetically using `compareTo()` string function but no idea about this.

This is what I have to do :

Method `isIncreasing()` to check whether the given string is an increasing  string or not. It is increasing if, while moving from Left to Right, each character in the string comes after the previous character in the alphabetical order.

Example: `ANT` is an increasing string whereas `APPLE` is not.

Comment: Is this homework or something?

Comment: What have you written so far?

Comment: By alphabets do you mean letters?

Comment: @Alboz nothing at first i thought of using compare to method but failed to do anything so currently i have no idea how to do it and it's only a small part of a question i am working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't do your homework for you, but here's an outline to get you started:

1. Create a `char` variable called for instance `last` to hold the previous letter.
2. Initialize it with `'\0'`
3. Iterate over the characters in the string. (Hint: `String.toCharArray`)
4. If current character is less than `last`

   4. Quit with the message *"not increasing"* otherwise continue to the next character
5. After the loop, quit with the message *"increasing"*.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) overriding the compare method to compare the letters short-value ( just cast to short ) in a for-loop for each letters limited by Math.min(o1.length, o2.length).

Comment: If it's just about comparing characters, an ordinary `<` comparison would do fine.